# Python: Trying to create two functions. One iterates through the columns of a 2d list, while the other goes through the rows

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, for-loop, multidimensional-array

```
def average_hour (temps, hour):
      i = 0
      for i in temps[None][i]:
            total = total + temps[None][i]
      average = total/(i+1)
      return average

def average_day (temps, day):
      i = 0
      for i in temps[i][None]:
            total = total + temps[i][None]
      average = total/(i+1)
      return average      

def main():
      temps = [
      [73.0, 73.9, 73.0, 73.9, 73.9, 73.9, 73.0, 71.1, 71.1, 71.1, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 71.1, 71.1, 71.6, 71.1, 71.1, 70.0, 71.1, 70.0, 71.1],
      [63.0, 63.0, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 61.0, 62.6, 62.6, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 62.1],
      [68.0, 68.0, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 73.9, 75.0, 75.9, 81.0, 81.0, 82.0, 84.0, 80.1, 78.1, 75.9, 77.0, 80.1, 81.0, 82.0, 81.0, 81.0, 79.0, 78.1, 78.1],
      [78.1, 78.1, 78.1, 77.0, 77.0, 77.0, 75.9, 75.0, 75.2, 75.9, 73.9, 73.9, 73.9, 73.0, 73.0, 73.0, 73.9, 73.9, 73.0, 73.4, 73.0, 73.0, 75.0, 75.0],
      [71.1, 71.1, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 68.0, 66.9, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 64.9, 64.9],
      [61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 60.1, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 64.9, 64.9],
      [57.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 54.0, 54.0, 55.0, 54.0, 55.0, 55.9, 55.9, 55.0, 55.0, 57.0, 62.1, 66.9, 71.1, 73.0, 75.0, 77.0, 78.1, 78.1, 78.1, 75.9],
      [62.1, 61.0, 61.0, 60.1, 60.1, 59.0, 59.0, 61.0, 66.9, 72.0, 75.9, 78.1, 78.1, 78.1, 78.1, 78.1, 77.0, 75.0, 72.0, 71.1, 70.0, 68.0, 66.0, 64.0],
      [63.0, 62.1, 61.0, 61.0, 59.0, 60.1, 59.0, 60.1, 66.9, 73.9, 75.9, 78.1, 81.0, 79.0, 81.0, 79.0, 79.0, 75.9, 73.0, 72.0, 71.1, 71.1, 71.1, 70.0],
      [70.0, 69.1, 70.0, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 69.1, 68.0, 68.0, 68.0, 70.0, 69.8, 70.0, 70.0, 70.0, 71.1, 70.0, 70.0, 71.1, 71.1, 71.1, 73.0, 73.0],
      [61.0, 61.0, 60.1, 59.0, 59.0, 59.0, 57.9, 59.0, 59.0, 60.1, 61.0, 61.0, 63.0, 66.9, 66.0, 71.1, 71.1, 73.9, 72.0, 75.9, 75.0, 75.9, 75.9, 75.0],
      [62.1, 62.1, 62.1, 61.0, 62.1, 61.0, 62.1, 62.1, 63.0, 62.1, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 64.0, 64.9, 66.0, 66.0, 68.0, 70.0, 66.0, 64.0, 62.1, 62.1],
      [63.0, 63.0, 64.0, 64.0, 64.9, 63.0, 63.0, 64.0, 68.0, 72.0, 75.0, 77.0, 79.0, 79.0, 79.0, 79.0, 78.1, 75.9, 73.0, 72.0, 71.1, 71.1, 70.0, 69.1],
      [69.1, 68.0, 66.0, 66.0, 64.9, 64.0, 64.0, 63.0, 63.0, 64.0, 64.0, 64.0, 64.9, 68.0, 73.0, 75.0, 77.0, 79.0, 80.1, 80.1, 79.0, 77.0, 71.1, 64.0],
      [57.9, 57.9, 59.0, 59.0, 57.0, 55.9, 55.0, 55.0, 60.1, 64.9, 70.0, 73.0, 73.0, 73.9, 75.0, 73.9, 75.0, 72.0, 61.0, 57.0, 55.9, 54.0, 53.1, 53.1],
      [53.1, 53.1, 52.0, 52.0, 51.1, 51.1, 54.0, 55.0, 64.0, 69.1, 73.0, 77.0, 79.0, 81.0, 81.0, 81.0, 78.1, 75.0, 73.0, 72.0, 68.0, 66.9, 66.0, 66.0],
      [62.1, 61.0, 57.9, 57.0, 57.0, 55.0, 54.0, 54.0, 57.0, 63.0, 66.0, 66.9, 70.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 71.1, 68.0, 63.0, 57.9, 59.0, 55.0, 55.0, 53.1],
      [53.1, 51.1, 48.9, 48.0, 46.9, 45.0, 44.1, 45.0, 48.0, 51.1, 54.0, 55.0, 55.9, 57.9, 59.0, 60.1, 59.0, 57.0, 52.0, 46.9, 46.0, 43.0, 45.0, 42.1],
      [42.1, 39.9, 39.9, 39.9, 39.9, 39.0, 37.9, 39.9, 45.0, 50.0, 55.0, 57.0, 59.0, 60.1, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 57.9, 52.0, 48.0, 46.9, 45.0, 45.0, 45.0],
      [45.0, 43.0, 43.0, 43.0, 42.1, 42.1, 42.1, 43.0, 52.0, 57.0, 61.0, 64.0, 68.0, 70.0, 71.1, 70.0, 69.1, 66.9, 62.1, 57.0, 54.0, 54.0, 53.1, 52.0],
      [51.1, 50.0, 50.0, 51.1, 51.1, 51.1, 50.0, 52.0, 57.9, 64.0, 70.0, 73.0, 75.0, 75.0, 75.9, 75.0, 73.0, 70.0, 66.9, 63.0, 62.1, 60.1, 60.8, 61.0],
      [55.9, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 57.0, 55.9, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 53.1, 53.1],
      [57.0, 55.9, 55.0, 54.0, 54.0, 53.1, 53.1, 54.0, 54.0, 53.1, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 54.0, 53.1, 53.1, 53.1, 62.1, 68.0, 73.0, 77.0],
      [63.0, 59.0, 57.9, 57.9, 55.9, 55.9, 55.0, 55.9, 60.1, 63.0, 66.0, 69.1, 72.0, 72.0, 73.9, 73.0, 70.0, 68.0, 64.0, 61.0, 59.0, 61.0, 57.9, 57.9],
      [55.9, 55.9, 55.0, 55.0, 54.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.0, 55.9, 57.0, 57.0, 57.9, 61.0, 64.0, 68.0, 73.0, 75.9, 78.1, 78.1, 77.0, 78.1],
      [64.9, 66.0, 64.9, 64.0, 64.0, 63.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 61.0, 63.0, 66.9, 64.0, 66.0, 64.0, 64.0, 64.0, 62.1, 61.0, 60.1, 59.0, 57.9, 57.9, 57.9],
      [57.9, 57.9, 57.9, 57.9, 57.9, 57.9, 57.0, 57.9, 59.0, 60.1, 59.0, 60.1, 60.1, 61.0, 63.0, 64.9, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 66.9, 66.9, 66.0, 66.0],
      [70.0, 70.0, 71.1, 71.1, 71.1, 71.1, 70.0, 70.0, 69.1, 71.1, 71.1, 73.0, 73.9, 75.9, 77.0, 73.9, 73.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0, 72.0],
      [72.0, 71.1, 71.1, 71.1, 70.0, 68.0, 68.0, 68.0, 66.2, 66.9, 66.0, 66.0, 69.1, 70.0, 70.0, 73.0, 73.9, 75.9, 77.0, 79.0, 78.1, 75.0, 72.0, 69.1],
      [66.9, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 66.0, 64.9, 64.0, 63.0, 64.0, 66.0, 69.1, 71.1, 73.0, 73.0, 73.0, 73.9, 73.0, 70.0, 61.0, 59.0, 57.0, 55.9, 54.0, 53.1],
      [51.1, 51.1, 51.1, 51.1, 51.1, 52.0, 51.1, 51.1, 54.0, 60.1, 64.0, 66.0, 68.0, 69.1, 68.0, 68.0, 66.9, 64.9, 63.0, 60.1, 59.0, 60.1, 57.9, 57.0]
      ]

      print("Average Hour:", average_hour(temps, 0)) # Should be ~61.3
      print("Average Day:", average_day(temps, 0))  # Should be ~71.5
```

I reference `main()` to test it. In the end, it tells me that `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not NoneType`

What should be an appropriate placeholder for that then instead of `None`? Also, am I doing the for loop right?

Please let me know. Newbie here (as it is inherently obvious).

Comment: What is `temps[i][None]` supposed to be doing? How could None be an index?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham

Yeah, but what should the placeholder by for 'None' then?

Comment: You have not declared total, used hour or day either, how do hour and day fit into your logic?

Comment: what are the roles of `day` and `hour` parameters?

Comment: Alright, could I just write `total = 0` in the beginning of both `average_hour` and `average_day`?

Comment: @CPanda
@PadraicCunningham

`day` and `hour` specify the days and hours for which I am taking the average of.

Not sure where I can fit those in. I guess I don't need the `i` variable at all. Perhaps I could use `day` and `hour` instead respectively?

Comment: @Help_Python_Pls,  ado you mean something like  `average = sum(sum(col, 0.0) / len(col) for col in zip(*temps)) / len(temps[0])` for the columns?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham

What does `zip(*temps))` mean?

Comment: It transposes the list of lists `[[1,2],[3,4]] -> [(1,3),(2,4)]`, for the rows you would just sum each sublist/row `sum(sum(row) / len(row) for row in temps) / len(temps)`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham

Makes sense. Also, what does `0.0` do? Does it serve as a floating point place holder?

Comment: @Help_Python_Pls, it means if you had no floats you would not get floor division so the code would work the same for python2 and 3.

Comment: @Help_Python_Pls read the docs for `zip` if you are going to a lot of data transformation. It is indispensible. Anyway, I have posted an answer, check.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham

Alright, will check that out. Thanks.

Comment: @Help_Python_Pls, in python you can also iterate over the sublists directly, you would not need to use an index. You can simply  `for row in temps:...`, what you do need is to set `total = 0` outside the loop. A loop with the rows would look like http://pastebin.com/qaGjHzkG

Comment: What does `+=` do?

And in that code that you pasted, where is `row` defined?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham

Makes sense. The columns are the days. There are 30 columns for 30 days. The rows are the hours. 24 hours in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are indeed using `None` as an index. Instead, for `average_hour`, you should iterate over all hours of a fixed day (not None). Similar for `average_day`:

```
def average_hour(temps, hour):
    total = 0
    for day in temps:  # each row is a day (list of hours)
        total += day[hour]  # take specified hour from each row (day)
    average = total / len(temps)
    return average

def average_day(temps, day):
    total = 0
    for hour in temps[day]:  # just iterate over the specified row (aka day)
        total += hour
    average = total / len(temps[day])
    return average

> print(average_hour(temps, 0))
> print(average_day(temps, 0))

61.3064516129
71.5041666667
```

As mentioned in the comments, there are ways to shorten this. One of the more readable ways uses [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (or the underlying [generator-expression](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#generators) as pointed out by @PadraicCunningham), e.g.:

```
def average_hour(temps, hour):
    days = [day[hour] for day in temps]
    return sum(days)/len(days)
    # or even shorter: return sum(day[hour] for day in temps)/len(temps)

def average_day(temps, day):
    return sum(temps[day])/len(temps[day])
```

Comment: Alright. That works. Now for my questions so I understand this correctly!

So why is it `for day` in the `average_hour` function and `for hour` in the `average_day` function?

Also, what does the `+=` do?

Comment: `sum(row[day] for row in temps) / len(temps)`

Comment: `for thing in things` is the pythonical way to iterate over the elements of an iterable (e.g. a `list`). `x += y` is a short-cut for `x = x + y`

Comment: @schwobaseggl

Yes, I get that we are iterating. But why are we using essentially the opposites. Like we used `hour` in the `day` function.

Also, alright. The `+=` makes sense now.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Given the involved length of temps (31) and its rows (24) , `sum(temps[day]) / len(temps[day])` seems more likely

Comment: @Help_Python_Pls In order to get the average for a day, you iterate over this day's hours, and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, yep that was meant for hours not days

Comment: @schwobaseggl

Oh yeah. Makes sense. I was thinking of it wrongly.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham The result would be the same. However, you seemed to assume that we were given `day` as a parameter where, based on the data, `hour` makes more sense. `row` should represent a day, thus, `row[day]` makes less sense than `row[hour]`